# ignore touch when FMDB do database method

Tags: ios, database, fmdb

is there any way to ignore touch event before fmdb complete it's database sequence

for instance, i do a database pulling so i dont want user to tap on the screen before the database process completed

i've tried using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];

[databaseHandler saveAllData];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

but it doesn't work

thanks

Comment: use UIActivityIndicatorView while you fetching data.

Comment: You might try SVProgressHUD, that can gray out the screen and also inform the user something is happening - https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD